# issue when importing use custom hook library

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

I am getting an invalid hook call error, can anyone help me to solve this! when importing a file from the package it shows the below error, but when using the same file in project dir it doesn't throw an error.

error

```
react.development.js:1465 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

code

```
import './App.css';

import { useToggle } from "use-custom-hooks";
// import useToggle from "./useToggle"
const Mood = () => {
  const [isHappy, toggleIsHappy] = useToggle(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <p>{`The user is ${isHappy ? "Happy " : "Sad "}`}</p>
      <button onClick={toggleIsHappy}>Toggle</button>
    </div >
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Mood />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but when I am using it as a separate file, it works

example

```
import './App.css';

import useToggle from "./useToggle"
const Mood = () => {
  const [isHappy, toggleIsHappy] = useToggle(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <p>{`The user is ${isHappy ? "Happy " : "Sad "}`}</p>
      <button onClick={toggleIsHappy}>Toggle</button>
    </div >
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Mood />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is in a separate file in the same dir

```
import { useState } from 'react';

/**
 *
 * Custom hook which returns a boolean state and a state toggle function.
 *
 * @param {boolean} initialValue Initial value of the state.
 * @returns {Array} Array containing boolean state and a state toggle function.
 */
const useToggle = (initialValue) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const toggleValue = () => {
    setValue((currentValue) => !currentValue);
  };

  return [value, toggleValue];
};

export default useToggle;
```

Comment: Would you kindly share which is the nom package you're trying to import from?

Comment: package: **use-custom-hooks**

Comment: Which version of React are you using? Are you using React in a monorepo?

Comment: react version:18 , monorepo:yes

Comment: @MaheshM did you ever solve this? I just ran into the same issue. So weird.